# Block.json editorScript path references plugin directory

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I am using block.json in a WordPress theme for each block withhin  but the editorScript is referencing the plugins directory and not the theme.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For themes, you should use [theme.json](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/themes/theme-json/), the newly embraced practice for defining properties for the block editor. [Part of theme.json](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/themes/theme-json/#block-styles) provides for individual blocks and the contents are what you are using for block.json. I think block.json should be reserved for use in plugins where it defines the settings of individual blocks. Use theme.json for defining global settings, including blocks, if contained in the theme.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour was reported as a bug and will be fixed in Wordpress version **6.0**.

**Github pull request**:

https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/pull/2494